# Wordpress Version 5 keeps asking for database update every day

Tags: database, wordpress, sql-update

I got Wordpress 5.1.1 and it keeps asking me to update the database every single day. The update then takes a split second and is successful.
The problem is that users can register on that page and will be prompted to update the database as well which is very unprofessional.
Has anyone had the same problem and maybe a fix for that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are problem in cache of server side.

Contact the server support to clear it

OR

Go to /wp-admin/options.php.
Fill the field db_upgraded with a 0 (zero).
Hit Save Changes.

Done.

Comment: I own the server so I'll see what has to be done there.
Anyway I did the db_upgraded thing and will observe tomorrow if that's fixed.
Thanks for you quick answer!

Comment: Hi, so I checked back today and it was still there. Also the value 0 was not there anymore in db_upgraded. Any ideas? I am using W3 Cache. Will delete it completely now and check back.

Comment: can yo deactivate W3 Cache

Comment: stop all cache server side